# number of lattice points in an n-ball

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, integer-lattices, geometry-of-numbers

I have faced a problem in my work and I will appreciate any hint/reference as I am not much into the lattice problems.

Assume an n-dimensional lattice $\Lambda_n$ with generator matrix $G$. Note that lattice points are not necessarily integer, i.e., $x\in \mathbb{R}$ where $x$ is a lattice point. Is there a way to count/estimate/bound the number of lattice points inside and on an n-ball?

any hint or reference to appropriate literature is appreciated

Comment: You mean to say that the lattice points are the images of some integer lattice under a linear transformation, and therefore $x\in\mathbb R^n$? So you might as well ask for integer lattice points in some $n$-dimensional paraboloid. Not that I think that formulation is any easier, mind, just thinking out loud. What kind of performance are you looking for? Would a scan conversion which gives an exact answer $m$ (i.e. there are $m$ points inside the ball) in time $O\left(m^{(n-1)/n}\right)$ be preferable to one which uses the bounding box for a very loose bound in $O(1)$?

Comment: I was googling about the lattice points in an n-ball and found some papers about integer lattices (Gauss' circle problem) but in my problem the lattice is not integer. With $x\in \mathbb{R}$ I mean that the entries of the lattice point (vector $x$) are real numbers.
I am not sure if the exact number of the lattice points inside an n-ball is solved but even a bound can be enough to proceed with my problem.

Comment: What do you mean by “solved”? Sure you can compute that number, a brute force enumeration will yield the count eventually. On the other hand, a closed formula might be unrealistic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The $n$-volume of the fundamental parallelotope is the absolute value of the determinant of $G.$

The $n$-volume of the ball of radius $1$ is, in shorthand, $\pi^{n/2}/ (n/2)!,$ or
$$ \omega_n = \frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma \left( 1 + \frac{ n}{2}  \right)}.  $$ The volume of the ball of radius $R$ is $\omega_n R^n. $

So, there is your estimate of the count, $\omega_n R^n / |G|.$

Comment: Are you aware of a reference for this fact?

Comment: @jvnv looked at your posts, not sure what part of this could be a problem for you. The volume of the ball should be in any mathematical statistics book; the easiest method is induction by 2, even/odd dimension, using polar coordinates for the integral. Note that I am assuming $G$ expresses a basis of the lattice as its rows, so the Gram matrix is actually $G G^T.$ For anything in that area, try SPLAG by Conway and Sloane. Sphere Packing Lattices and Groups

Comment: None of the parts is a problem for me, but I was just curious whether you had a reference for this fact. I expect this reasoning to be packed as a result somewhere. I will have a look into the book by Conway and Sloane; thanks for pointing this out.